# Writing a function that accepts a list as argument

Tags: haskell

I started to study Haskell to prepare myself for next semester (I, in fact, dropped it early last semester) and I have been successfully writing some basic functions. The subject I am actually reviewing is Lists and I need help to write a very simple function called cons8 that accepts an argument which is a list and adds (cons) an 8 to the beginning of such a list. My issue is that I am stuck on how to include a list as an argument of the function and how to refer to it in the function´s body. I guess that I can define the type as follows, and then write the function:

```
cons8 :: [a] -> [a]
```

I will very much appreciate your help to solve my issue.

Comment: Your type signature suggests that `cons8` can work with lists of any type, but if you want to put an `8` in the list, it needs to be a list of numbers.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, but it's an easy answer anyways:  you need to put two definitions below which it will pattern match, one for empty list and one for non, two lines:  `cons8 [] = (your empty case code here)`, `cons8 (x:xs) = (non-empty case, x pattern matches to the head and is of type a, xs to the rest of the list and is type [a])`.  `cons8` wouldn't need an empty case though, I hope you can see why--it's not manipulating the head, just doing something with the list itself.

Comment: Also, the easy one line answer is to convert the infix function to prefix to take advantage of currying (I think that's correct terminology).  `cons8 = (:) 8`

Comment: @j.i.h., since there is no need to pattern match here, I think you're just confusing things.

Answer (score 6):

First, starting from the type is indeed a good way to start.

Let's check the type:

```
cons8 :: [a] -> [a]
```

Here, `a` can be any type. The type above promises that the caller can use `cons8` with any list: a list of integers, a list of chars, a list of booleans, etc. Since we want to prepend 8, and list contain values of the same type, we can see that the type above is too general. Let's use something less general, e.g.

```
cons8 :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

Now, how to take a list argument. This is important: you take a list argument as any other argument.

```
cons8 x = ???? -- TODO
```

A common mistake here is to write `cons8 [n] = ...` since it's a list. Don't do that! `[n]` is a list, but a very special one: a list with only one element (`n`). We don't want to handle only one-element lists, we want `cons8` to work with *any* list. So, no braces: let `x` be the whole list argument.

Then, we can just apply the cons operator:

```
cons8 x = 8 : x
```

Of course, we can rename `x` to any other name, e.g.

```
cons8 list = 8 : list
```

would also work.

When you get ahead in Haskell, you'll probably learn about sections, and prefer the following code

```
cons8 = (8 :)
```

Indeed, `(8 :)` is so short that you usually avoid defining a `cons8` function, and directly use its definition.

Comment: Only a minor style point, I would use `cons8 xs = 8 : xs` to indicate that it's a list

Comment: Great explanation. I am very greatful.